# Modifying OWIN OAuth middleware to use JWT bearer tokens

Tags: c#, owin, asp.net-web-api2, jwt

I'm currently trying to create a proof of concept for claims based authentication for a new app using a combination of the following technologies: Web API 2, OWIN middleware and JWT.

To keep things simple I started with the Web API 2 project template and changed the authentication to 'Individual User Accounts'. The sample client I created was then able to get a token by calling /Token and was able to call a sample endpoint with the OAuth bearer token. So far so good. I then added the following code to Startup.Auth.cs to try and enable JwtBearerAuthentication:

```
    var jwtOptions = new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AllowedAudiences = audiences,
        IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new[] { 
            new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, signingKey) }
    };

    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(jwtOptions);
```

I expected that Web API 2 would start returning JWTs from the call to /Token, but it doesn't appear to have done anything. I've been banging my head against this for a few days with no success and the Microsoft documents aren't very forthcoming.

I also tried adding the following to my OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions

```
AuthorizationCodeFormat = new JwtFormat(audience, new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, signingKey))
```

I could also be trying to doing the completely wrong thing.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm currently in the process of creating my own ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> and assigning it to AccessTokenFormat

Comment: Did you work out a way to change to issuing JWT using your own custom ISecureDataFormat implementation?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm starting to look at doing the same thing now.

Comment: @ChrisC yes. Ended up creating a custom AccessTokenFormat based on ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>. The unprotect method was similar to the following: https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt/JwtFormat.cs and we implemented an appropriate protect method.

Answer (score 6):

Well, now there is a setting on `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions` that you can specify the format of your access token, not the authorization code, like you're doing on you example.

So, instead of:

```
AuthorizationCodeFormat = new JwtFormat(audience, new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, signingKey))
```

You should have:

```
AccessTokenFormat = new JwtFormat(audience, new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, signingKey))
```

Comment: The two code examples seem identical, bar the variable name.

Comment: @RobertGrant yes, because this answer is saying that the `AccessTokenFormat` property should be assigned instead of the `AuthorizationCodeFormat` property.  That is, they're not variables but property names from the object initializer (for the OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions object).

Comment: @phoog got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The Windows Identity Foundation uses a proprietary token format, not JWT. The JWT code you see above is for *consuming* tokens, not generating them. There is a helpful discussion on the [ASP.NET forums](http://forums.asp.net/t/2013277.aspx?How%20to%20use%20JWT%20bearer%20token%20with%20OAuth%20in%20MVC%20).

However, in the second half of 2014 Microsoft officially released support for JWT in Windows Identity foundation, with the [JSON Web Token Handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn205065.aspx). You should be able to install and use that package to solve the problem you have described.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any current way to override how the token is output in the response. I took a look at the OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler in the Katana [source code repository](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth/OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler.cs).

You'll see that in the InvokeTokenEndpointAsync method, there is a section that creates a JsonTextWriter which generates the response. It is not done in such a way that any kind of extension would affect it.

I find this frustrating too. Microsoft's library should have some way to easily override the response serialization. You can't even add your own custom parameters to the response.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this sample https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/tree/master/samples/OAuth2/EmbeddedResourceOwnerFlow

for writting authentication logic in your project.
After it you must add [Authorize] attribute to each controller or action which requires authorization(OWIN Katana contains the logic of validating token, authorization and some other useful things).

Comment: The given sample URL does not target the JWT based auth. Or did I miss something?